# Filtering by excluding multiple criteria in the same column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to pull information from one sheet that excludes info for a list of IDs I have in another sheet.

Sheet 1 with IDs to exclude:

| Id |
| --- |
| A |
| B |

Sheet 2 with additional information:

| Id | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | $500 |
| A | $600 |
| A | $700 |
| B | $200 |
| B | $300 |
| B | $400 |
| C | $30 |
| C | $40 |
| C | $50 |

I would like returned all information from Sheet 2 that excludes the IDs in Sheet 1. The result I want:

| Id | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| C | $30 |
| C | $40 |
| C | $50 |

I only know how to filter for information that INCLUDES the IDs in Sheet 1 using this:

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!A2:B,INDEX(COUNTIFS(A2:A,Sheet2!A2:A)))
```

but I cannot figure out how to tweak this formula to instead EXCLUDE those IDs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with MATCH and ISNA to return TRUE when the value is not found:

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!A2:B,INDEX(ISNA(MATCH(Sheet2!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A,0))))
```